# Helping and FoRKs on a beginner's luck test

Tags: burning-wheel, skills

Which of the following scenarios are possible (under suitable fictional circumstances, of course)?

- Rolling a skill with beginner's luck, helping with a skill
- Rolling a skill with beginner's luck, helping with a stat
- Rolling a skill with beginner's luck, helping by beginner's lucking a stat (I doubt this one, personally...)

In the last case I mean something like Abelard is rolling beginner's luck philosopher-wise. Can Heloise help with her beginner's luck philosopher-wise, which amounts to perception?

What about the same questions when forking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *The First Rule of Help (BWG 36):*
>
> Skills may help skills and stats. Stats may help stats. Stats may not help skills. Circles may help Circles (if appropriate). Resources may help Resources.

A beginner's luck roll is a stat test (because you're learning the skill).

- Rolling beginner's luck, another player helping with a relevant skill: **Yes**, helping a stat with a skill.
- Rolling beginner's luck, helping with a stat: **Yes**, helping a stat with a stat, assuming it makes narrative sense. For the helper, this counts as a stat test instead of a test toward learning the skill (BWG 46).
- Rolling beginner's luck, helping with beginner's luck: **Yes**, helping a stat with a stat.

For Fields of Related Knowledge, skills can help skills, subject to it making sense (GM arbitrates). Stats and attributes may never FoRK (BWG 37).  FoRKs are never relevant for beginner's luck rolls because they are stat rolls.